# How can I access value of JSON object in android listview?

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to access "area" value, which is inside "address" object in list view . Please see in the image of json .[image: JSON data image]

I want to parse json data in list view but I'm not able to access area which is inside of Address. I'm getting null after use of this code .

see in the image i am getting area as null.

[image: Area_null]

How can I get the area ?

listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Restaurant name  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->
   <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
<!--
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://sewqusviwc.localtunnel.me/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=10&page=1&sort_col=average_ratings";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Custom list adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
        TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        // rating
        average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
        address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
        cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
        /*// genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

        return convertView;
    }
```

Movie.java

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings,String area,String cuisine,String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see in your code where you call `Movie.setAddress`?

Comment: when i called movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));then i am getting whole address while i want only area .
i am getting after calling address
area : "Matunga East"
full_address : "Bhandarkar Road, Matunga East, Mumbai,Matunga East,mumbai,maharashtra,india,"

Comment: You need to call something like `movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"))`

Answer (score 3):

Create Address Model class:

Address.java:

```
class Address {

    private String area;
    private String fullAddress;

    public void set(String are){this.area = area;}
    public void set(String are){this.fullAddress= fullAddress;}

    public String getArea(){return area;}
    public String getFullAddress(){return fullAddress;}

}
```

You should have a address setter and getter methods in Movie Model class.
Parsing only address json object from the main json, like wise you have to parse other objects from main json Object.

Json Parsing:

```
                   // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                            //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                            movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                            movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                            //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                           if(obj.has("address")){
                              JSONObject addressJsonObj = obj.getJSONObject("address");
                              Address address = new Address();
                              address.setArea(addressJsonObj.getString("area"));
                              address.setFullAddress(addressJsonObj.getString("full_address"));
                              movie.setAddress(address);
                            }

                           // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort .I have required only area Which i got by use of movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));

Answer (score 1):

After obj creation:

```
JSONObject adressObject = obj.getJSONObject("adress");
String area = adressObject.get("area").toString();
```